# Why is notebook() not working for IJulia?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, conda, ijulia-notebook

I am receiving this issue while trying to use `notebook()` in Julia (Command Line Interface REPL)

```
julia> using IJulia
[ Info: Precompiling IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]

julia> notebook()
[ Info: running setenv(`/root/miniconda3/bin/jupyter notebook`,["_CE_M=", "LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", "PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/condabin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/root/julia-1.3.1/bin", "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus", "XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0", "XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=GNOME", "SSH_AGENT_PID=2661", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11", "QT_IM_MODULE=ibus", "USER=root", "PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/0/kwallet5.socket", "LESS=-R", "CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base) ", "XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/root/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share", "CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=ibus", "SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh", "GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr", "XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority", "XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-", "GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge", "GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus", "MANAGERPID=2575", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2753,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2753", "XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus", "_CE_CONDA=", "CONDA_SHLVL=1", "CONDA_EXE=/root/miniconda3/bin/conda", "HOME=/root", "TERM=xterm-256color", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "VTE_VERSION=5802", "CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/root/miniconda3/bin/python", "INVOCATION_ID=a29cdf2f60b140acb65b8e9d69af5b77", "IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1", "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME", "LANG=C.UTF-8", "LOGNAME=root", "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated", "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0", "SHLVL=1", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/0/keyring/ssh", "DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-xorg", "OLDPWD=/root", "_=/root/julia-1.3.1/bin/julia", "PAGER=less", "CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base", "GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1", "GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/73a7f463_14d7_4c04_adfb_a849e0d337b9", "ZSH=/root/.oh-my-zsh", "GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.261", "PWD=/root/JuliaPro-1.2.0-2", "XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user", "DISPLAY=:0", "GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG", "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1", "CONDA_PREFIX=/root/miniconda3", "JOURNAL_STREAM=9:29944", "QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:", "OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"])
Process(setenv(`/root/miniconda3/bin/jupyter notebook`,["_CE_M=", "LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", "PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/condabin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/root/julia-1.3.1/bin", "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus", "XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0", "XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=GNOME", "SSH_AGENT_PID=2661", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11", "QT_IM_MODULE=ibus"  …  "PWD=/root/JuliaPro-1.2.0-2", "XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user", "DISPLAY=:0", "GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG", "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1", "CONDA_PREFIX=/root/miniconda3", "JOURNAL_STREAM=9:29944", "QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:", "OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"]; dir="/root"), ProcessExited(1))
```

This is very confusing and likely a beginner issue.

As suggested by @SalchiPapa , here is my versioninfo:

```
Julia Version 1.3.1
Commit 2d5741174c (2019-12-30 21:36 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

Also, the `jupyter notebook` starts up the localhost for me but kernel keeps having errors for `julia-1.3.1` . This doesn't work for me as it shows this error : `ERROR: LoadError: Blosc not installed properly, run Pkg.build("ZMQ"), restart Julia and try again` and this one at the same time : `ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile ZMQ [c2297ded-f4af-51ae-bb23-16f91089e4e1] to /root/.julia/compiled/v1.3/ZMQ/CaaO6_riTu7.ji.`

Manually tried to Pkg.add and Pkg.build each of ZMQ, Blosc and CMake but to no success.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to add tracebacks in Stack Overflow especially when tracebacks itself contain ` backticks .

Comment: Could you please share the output of your `versioninfo()`? I just tried in Windows 10 and it worked. Calling `notebook()` opens a new tab in my default browser pointing to `http://localhost:8888/tree`. If this tab didn't open could you try browsing manually to it? If you don't want `notebook()` to block your Julia REPL, call it this way: `notebook(detached = true)`.

Comment: @SalchiPapa check my edited answer

Comment: Also, the `jupyter notebook` starts up the localhost for me but kernel keeps having errors for `julia-1.3.1` . This doesn't work for me as it shows this error : `ERROR: LoadError: Blosc not installed properly, run Pkg.build("ZMQ"), restart Julia and try again` and this one at the same time : `ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile ZMQ [c2297ded-f4af-51ae-bb23-16f91089e4e1] to /root/.julia/compiled/v1.3/ZMQ/CaaO6_riTu7.ji.`

Comment: I have tried to manually `Pkg.add("Blosc")` `Pkg.add("ZMQ")` `Pkg.add("CMake")` and `Pkg.build` all of them but to no success

Comment: have you tried running `using Pkg; Pkg.build("ZMQ")` as suggested? Please also append the output of `using Pkg; Pkg.status()`

Comment: It's `Pkg.build()` with the parenthesis.

Comment: using Pkg;Pkg.status()
    Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.3/Project.toml`
 [a74b3585] Blosc v0.5.1
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.20.0
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.20.2
  [739be429] MbedTLS v0.7.0
  [612083be] Queryverse v0.3.1
  [c2297ded] ZMQ v1.2.0

Comment: I sent you private chat message

Comment: Problem was he was using Kali Linux (which uses `root` by default ‍♂️). When reporting an issue, allways put output of: `versioninfo()`, `Pkg.status()` and `$ uname -a` if uname doesn't show the distro name, also provide that :) Maybe we need an `allow_root = true` option n `IJulia.notebook`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Much thanks to [@SalchiPapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2374329/salchipapa) who took his time out to personally videocall me and solve the issue. Solution right now is to not run IJulia from root

What worked for me :

`$su user-not-root`

`$julia`

`using IJulia;notebook(detached=true)`
This should show ProcessRunning at the end.

`run(path/to/jupyter notebook list)` with pair of backticks inside run().

This gave me the url and token appended to it . That worked out well.

I suggest that the community help solve this issue.
I have linked this answer to a [Github issue here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/895)

Comment: Comment from @stevenj on the above Github issue :
You can always just run jupyter notebook --allow-root yourself. (All IJulia.notebook() does is invoke jupyter notebook for you.)

Running as root is a rare and dangerous enough operation that it seems fine to not provide an easy IJulia.notebook() interface to it … you should have to know what you are doing, and if you know what you are doing then invoking jupyter directly is easy.