# Julia - Jupyter Notebook setenv does not work

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, centos7, rhel7, ijulia-notebook

[Similar to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900896/why-is-notebook-not-working-for-ijulia)
I have installed Jupyter Notebook with IJulia.notebook(),

which works perfectly fine when I run it with '．．．/.julia/conda/3/bin/jupyter-notebook'.

However, when I attempt to run notebook() after prompting Julia, it just starts a process `running setenv` that does not seem to launch anything.

I am wondering if it could have something to do with the fact that it is trying to invoke a path containing a space instead of a hyphen ?

> setenv(．．．/.julia/conda/3/bin/jupyter notebook,

Or is there something more crucial ?